# Restructure this function with module pattern is possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, callback, anonymous-function

I'm trying to understand the following snippet of code as well as to make it work.
Basically it retrieves data from Flickr but every time I try to access it then the data is not defined. 
I've tried to access the data by defining the function cb as global, but I don't want to pollute the scope.

Any further idea to make it work?

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function cb(data) {
      //use returned data
    }

    (function () {

       var tags = 'rome';
       var script = document.createElement('script');
       script.src = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=cb&tags=' + tags;
       document.head.appendChild(script);

    })();

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Remove space character from string set at `script.src` value

Comment: @guest271314 that's a typo...it's not the problem

Comment: Remove space character at `"&j s"` from URL set at `script.src` to avoid error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jsonFlickrFeed is not defined`

Comment: it's just how I copied the code on here. That's not the problem.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem.

Comment: It appears to be working fine (though I did make the flickr URL https): https://jsbin.com/tijiqudesa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Note also, `cb` is a named function.

Comment: @JaromandaX `"&jsoncallback=cb"`

Comment: `defining the function cb as global` - it **has to be** global

Comment: @JaromandaX How would it look like then? Is there a better  way to write the above function?

Comment: it has to be a global function ... the way you've shown it in the question, it is a global function, and so it should work (unless your page is hosted https ... in that case it wont ... but you'd get a useful message in the developer tools console about that too) ... perhaps your actual code is quite different to the code you've shown

Comment: @JaromandaX I've added the complete snippet. It's meant to be called inside the html page as you can see. That's the actual code.

Comment: `script.src = location.protocol + '//api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&jsoncallback=cb&tags=' + tags;`

Comment: Your code works fine ... except if the page is served over https - check the console in that case you'll see an error along the lines of `Blocked loading mixed active content`

Comment: What browser are you using, by the way?

Comment: @JaromandaX Chrome only

Comment: _"but every time I try to access it then the data is not defined"_ ,_"That's the actual code."_ Where do you try to access `data`?

Comment: are you hosting the page using http or https?

Comment: "*every time I try to access it then the data is not defined*" - in the code you've shown us, `data` is never accessed anywhere?

Comment: I meant within the function cb I do the data manipulation.

Comment: Also, Is it possible to use a module pattern in this case?